# Problema con Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode, pygame

estoy aprendiendo a programar en pygame y el problema es que a la hora de dibujar un poligono me da un error de sintaxis en la linea que pone

> While True:

en cambio si comento esa linea todo me funciona correcto.El codigo es este:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import * 

 pygame.init()
 ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
 pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame")

 pygame.draw.circle(ventana,(80,70,120),(80,90),20)
 pygame.draw.rect(ventana,(130,70,70),(0,0,100,50))
 pygame.draw.polygon(ventana,(90,180,70),((80,90),((140,0),(91,106),(237,277),    (56,277),(0,106)))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Tambien me marca error en

> QUIT , pygame.init() y pygame.quit()

porque me dice que no existen dichos modulos ,en cambio a la hora de ejecutarlo funciona perfectamente , excepto por lo del poligono.¿Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto?
Estoy utilizando Windows , VSCode y Python 3.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el mensaje de error exacto  que obtienes? Por otro lado no sé si es que tu código está realmente así, o ha sido un problema al pegar el código en Stack Overflow, pero la indentación no es correcta. Todo el bloque de líneas entre `from pygame...` hasta el `while` debería estar más a la izquierda (sobra un espacio por delante en cada línea)

Comment: O cuando dices que te da error te refieres solo al editor, que te subraya en rojo la línea?

Comment: Hola Juan lo único que tienes (además de la identación comentada por abulafia) es un pequeño lio con los paréntesis en la línea anterior al `while` (`draw.polygon`), debería ser `pygame.draw.polygon(ventana,
                    (90, 180, 70), 
                    ((80, 90), (140, 0), (91, 106),(237, 277), (56, 277),(0, 106)))` Tienes un paréntesis de más en el segundo punto de la lista de puntos del polígono.

Comment: Lo del segundo error no es tal, es el  linter que se haace un lio con las extensiones en C... XD, posiblemente pylint... Si es así puedes añadir pygame a su lista blanca para que deje de mostrar advertencias.